# OSX: How to statically link a library and dynamically link the standard library?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, static-linking

How do I specify to clang to statically link a certain library (in my case SDL2) and dynamically link the standard library?

Using `-static` is not good, since the linker tries to statically link the standard library as well, which is prohibited in OSX. On the other hand, clang doesn't know `-Wl,-Bstatic`.

Comment: Are you trying to statically link a .dylib into your program?

Comment: The library has .a version available, too. (SDL2 in my case.)

Comment: When you pass a library with `-l` to Clang, the linker will always pick the .dylib over the .a if there is one. This is a bug known to Apple. You may be able to work around it by adding a dummy directory with a copy of the lib (or a link to it) to the library path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put your static libraries in, say, dir `./MyStaticLibs` and simply use `-L./MyStaticLibs/ -l<StaticLibraryName>`.

**Compiler prefers dynamic version over static version of library**

If you have your dynamic library (`random.dylib`) and static library (`random.a`)  in same directory then compiler will prefer and link with `.dylib` not `.a`

Answer (score 5):

You have only a couple of options: `-L` for directories and `-l` for library names.

You can do this in the simplest way by ensuring that the static library you want to link is named differently from the dynamic library.  Otherwise, you may find that the linker helpfully collects all of the references to shared libraries by name and links against *those*.  This is not an OSX-specific problem, but a feature common to many systems with shared libraries.

One way to ensure that you have the static library when it normally resides in a directory with the same-named library is to construct a symbolic link into a temporary directory, and use *that* with `-L`.

Something like this:

```
MYDIR=$(mktemp -d -t xxxxxx)
ln -sf /usr/local/libfoo.a ${MYDIR}/libfoo.a
clang -o foo -L${MYDIR} -l foo
rm -rf ${MYDIR}
```

Comment: This is absolutely horrible, but it is the only way I have found - especially since I want to use `-hidden-l` which prevents me from specifying the path without `-l` - do you know if what you are proposing is still the only way to do it in 2022?

Comment: Probably.  See [this](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-openbsd.html#problem_linker).